# Preserve timestamp when editing file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, string-formatting

I want to preserve the timestamp of the files I'm editing in a for loop

```
for files in $DIR/MDC*/$FILE
do
    # Need to get date here!
    dos2unix $files
    if grep -q $TYPE $files; then
        echo 'done'
    else
        sed -i "1s/^/$TYPE\n/" $files
    fi
    $DIR/crccalc/LDDR16.py $files
    # Use Date variable here to change it back

done
```

The issue is I need to get a formatted date string from the file so that I can do `touch -r` to revert the files date back once the loop has completed.

`stat` is not giving the me the format I need.

Required Format:

`YYMMDDhhmm`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a nice trick for this: using `touch -r reference_file`. That is, touch the file using the timestamp of another file as a reference.

From `man touch`:

```
   -r, --reference=FILE
          use this file's times instead of current time
```

And you may be asking: and how can this help you? Well, because you can create a dummy file `dummy` to work with:

- Before modifying a file you touch the `dummy` with the timestamp of the file `original_file` you want to modify.
- You modify the `original_file`.
- Then you touch the `original_file` using the timestamp of the `dummy` one.

All together:

```
for files in $DIR/MDC*/$FILE
do
    # copy its timestamp to `dummy_file`
    touch -r "$files" "dummy_file"

    # ...things...

    # Use Date variable here to change it back
    touch -r "dummy_file" "$files"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt that can be run straight from the terminal.

FIRST do step one, then start working with your files.

1. **Preserve old timestamps**.
   It operates from the current directory, excludes all hidden files, and saves it to the temporary file in `/tmp/files`. You can always change parameters, but better stay with `-printf '"%t" "%p"\n'` since the later `touch` command utilizes that.

   `find . ! -iname ".*" -printf '"%t" "%p"\n' -type f > /tmp/files`
2. **Modify your files** as much as you like
3. now create a file that helps you restoring the timestamps:

   `while read line; do echo touch -a -d $line >> job.sh; done < /tmp/times`
4. And finally apply the old dates to the modified files

   `sh job.sh`

Caveat: works for files with name spacing, special characters, but for instance no files with a `$` sign and ones with a double space in it.